# How to use automapper to map Parent of source type into a collection of destination type?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have these classes:

```
public class Source 
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public int Age Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SourceChild> SourceChildren { get; set; }
}

public class SourceChild 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string SourceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Source Source { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I was mapping these classes using these mappings:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<SourceChild, Destination>()
            .ForMember(item => item.ID, property => property.MapFrom(item => item.SourceId))
            .ForMember(item => item.Age, property => property.MapFrom(item => item.Source.Age));
```

Automapper maps the other two properties automatically. So everything works fine if I try to map `SourceChild` into `Destination` type. However now I have another class using source and destination types:

```
public class SourceUser 
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Source Source { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<Destination> Destinations { get; set; } 
}
```

To illustrate the situation better here is short description on the classes: I have `Source` object and `SourceChild` children objects. `SourceChild` objects contain information in different languages. When I map Source into `Destination` I want to input the Source object and receive output of a collection of destination objects. For each `SourceChild` object, `Source` object had, there should be one `Destination` object.`SourceUser` simply refers to `Source` with a 1-many relation. `DestinationUser` had a many - many retion with `Destination` class. In other words each `DestinationUser` has a list of all `Destinations` in all languages. So having all this in mind let's get back to the code.

I have had some luck in writing the code I need. I have come up with this:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<SourceUser, DestinationUser>()
                .AfterMap((source, destination) => Mapper.Map<Source, List<Destination>>(source.Source));

    Mapper.CreateMap<Source, List<Destination>>()
                    .AfterMap((source, destination) => Mapper.Map<List<SourceChild>, List<Destination>>(source.SourceChildren.ToList(), destination));
```

This works ALMOST well enough, there is one IF though. I am using queryable extensions to process the mapping. When I retrieve a collection of `DestinationUsers`, none of them have the property `Destinations` mapped. It appears as null. However, if I do the mapping manually like this:

```
SourceUser SourceUser = Db.GetSourceUser();
DestinationUser DestUser = Db.GetDestinationUser();
DestUser.Destinations = Mapper.Map<List<Destination>>(SourceUser.Source);
```

everythign works fine. A list fo DestinationUsers is mapped from the instance of Source.

is it possible to avoid manually calling the latter `Mapper.Map()` call? Also bear in mind, that the List Destinations may be changed into any other collection. I just want to have a Destination object for each `SourceChild` object `Source` had.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I was only one little step away from the solution I was after. All I needed was extending my mapping of `SourceUser` and `DestinationUser` classes to look like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceUser, DestinationUser>()
                .AfterMap((source, destination) => Mapper.Map<Source, List<Destination>>(source.Source, destination.Destinations));
```

Hope this helps someone, experiencing similar problems to the one I was facing :)